# Solving quadratic or higher degree congruence with very large modulus.

Tags: congruences

Is there any general way to solve a polynomial congruence with a very large modulus?

An example could be

$$
x^2-377x+1\equiv 0 \pmod {8683317618811886495518194401279999999 }
$$

or
$$
x^2-29478x\equiv 13^{67} \pmod {17^{2001}}
$$

Comment: the following briefly describe general way (and I think number theory books do too): http://www.cs.xu.edu/math/math302/08f/16_QuadraticCongruences.pdf and http://www.johndcook.com/blog/quadratic_congruences/ and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/160385/how-to-solve-this-quadratic-congruence-equation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can factor the modulus into coprime factors, you can solve the congruence with respect to each factor and then use the Chinese Remainder Theorem.  On the other hand, being able to solve $x^2 = a \mod m$ would give you 
the ability to factor $m$.

EDIT: For lots more on these questions, see ["Basic algorithms in number theory" by Joe Buhler and Stan Wagon](http://library.msri.org/books/Book44/files/02buhler.pdf)

Comment: And what would you do if you had a very large prime number as modulust (first example)? Is there any way to simplify that congruence?

Comment: The **modulus**, in this particular case, is a **large prime**.

Comment: Not all that large... Maple's msolve quickly returns NULL, because $5685$ is not a square mod $8683317618811886495518194401279999999$.

Answer (score -1):

Algorithms for this are included in Mathematica. E.g.:

Solve[x^2 - 29478*x == 13^67, x, Modulus -> 17^2001]

yields the two solutions in an eyeblink.