# How do I solve this congruence?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, congruences

I have some difficulties solving the following congruential equation.

$3n^2 + 2 ≡ 0\pmod 5,\ \forall\ n \in Z$

If I subtract both members by $-2$, I end up getting $3n^2 = -2\pmod 5$ and I can't continue from there. Can you help me?

Comment: But if $n = 0$ then $2 \neq 0(\mod 5)$, no?

Comment: Modulo $5$ we have $-2\equiv3$, so $3n^2\equiv3$. As $3$ is coprime to $5$ you can cancel that factor, and...

Comment: And I think this question has essentially been answered earlier. [This](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/160385/11619) is one of the most upvoted and most comprehensive hits. I would like to close this as a duplicate, but I'm not sure enough to do it "unilaterally".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modulo $5$, we have

$$3n^2 \equiv -2$$ $$\Leftrightarrow 6n^2 \equiv -4$$ $$\Leftrightarrow n^2 \equiv 1$$

$$\Leftrightarrow n \equiv 1 \vee n \equiv -1.$$

The solutions are therefore all those $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $n = 5k+1$ or $n = 5k-1$ for some $k \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Thank you. Are the solutions $n^2 = 5k + 1\ \forall k \in Z$?

Comment: Nope. What if $k = 1$? What if $k = -1$? I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

**hint**: Consider $n = 5k + r, 0 \leq r \leq 4$

Answer (score 0):

Next step is to divide by $3$.  Note that $3 \times 2 = 5+1$.

Answer (score 0):

$$
3n^2+2\equiv 3n^2-3\equiv 3(n-1)(n+1)\equiv 0 \mod{5}
$$
since $\gcd(3,5)=1$ and since $5$ is a prime number it follows that 
$$
n\equiv\pm1 \mod{5}
$$

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** $3n^2\equiv-2\pmod 5\implies3n^2\equiv3\pmod5\implies n^2\equiv1 \pmod5\implies n\equiv \pm1\pmod 5$