# How would I find integer solution sets for something like $K^2 = 6n + 15 $ or $K^2 = 6n + 28$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

Intro: so I'm basically trying to determine whether or not we can find integer solutions for even $n$-tuples of consecutive positive integers that sum to a square (e.g pairs, $4$-tuples, $6$-tuples etc). These sums would take the form

$K^2 =2n+1$

$K^2 =4n+6$

$K^2 =6n+15$

$K^2 =8n+28$

Just plugging into wolfram alpha seems to show that only $n=4$ doesn't have solutions. 
However, the other answers seem to be given by adding another variable and then for some reason $K$ can be expressed as a linear function and $n$ a quadratic. Is there an intelligent way to go about solving this?

What I tried to do was assume that a quadratic exists for $n$ and then I reached the result:

If we start with $K^2 = G n + \frac{G(G-1)}{2}$ where $G$ is even

Then $K = Gc+\frac{G}{2}$ for the new variable $G$

For a quadratic in $c$, $n =\alpha c^2 + \beta c + \gamma$, so

$(\alpha-G)c^2+(\beta-G)c + \frac{G}{4}+\frac{1}{2}+\gamma=0$

Unfortunately I have no idea where to go from here to find $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ in terms of $G$

Comment: I added a simpler method that uses modular arithmetic.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to write it as $K^2\equiv x\mod2x$. You should then be able to use [this method](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/160385/how-to-solve-this-quadratic-congruence-equation) to solve your equations. Note that $a\equiv b\mod c$ is equivalent to saying $a=b+c*n$, where $n$ is an integer.

Here are some examples:

$K^2=2n+1\implies K^2\equiv 1 \mod2\implies K\equiv1 \mod 2$

$K^2=4n+6\implies K^2\equiv 6 \mod4\implies K^2\equiv2\mod4$, which has no solution.

$K^2=6n+15\implies K^2\equiv15\mod6\implies K^2\equiv3\mod6\implies K\equiv3\mod6$